# ViewHolder worth it when ListItem consists of one TextView?

Tags: android, performance, listview, textview

Whenever I have lists with one TextView only I always wonder whether it is still worth using the ViewHolder pattern?

```
if(convertView == null){
//convertView = Inflate the view
}
((TextView)convertView).setText(getItem(position).x);
```

Would I gain any performance on using the ViewHolder here? To me it seems that the whole point of the holder is to cache .findViewById(R.id...) but in this case I dont even need to find any views since the base view is the one im looking for.

Comment: You're right!! In this case you should not use viewholder pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its useful only if you have to call `findViewById()` every time. In your case you need not search for a View, so, not required.

Answer (score 0):

You are right. The main aim of ViewHolders is to cache results of slow `findViewById`. It is not needed in your case.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is a good question. If you look at the presentation or Romain Guy

[http://www.google.com/events/io/2010/sessions/world-of-listview-android](http://www.google.com/events/io/2010/sessions/world-of-listview-android.html)

he shows at 12:38 some speed result showing the performance improvement in the presence of images and by comparing to the use of `findViewById`.

As you say the goal is to cache the results instead of using `findViewById`, so it is useless in your case.